# Converting array to percentage in Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I fine tuned a model and return the predictions into the variable result  but I got a array of floats. How can I convert this to percentage and print it with the labels. Also how to return the top 5 predictions.

```
result = model.predict(test_image) 



print (result)

[[6.4043561e-05 4.0387777e-06 5.7413094e-05 4.3322724e-01 4.8211630e-05


 3.2328039e-03 5.4211664e-04 5.6212872e-01 6.7689107e-04 1.8414050e-05]]
```

My labels are stored in class indices

```
test_labels = test_batches.classes
test_labels

test_batches.class_indices
{'Name1': 0,
'Name2': 1,
'Name3': 2,
'Name4': 3,
'Name5': 4,
'Name6': 5,
'Name7': 6,
'Name8': 7,
'Name9': 8,
'Name10': 9}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what you want is to get the accuracy of your model as the percentage of correctly classified examples. The values in the array are probably logits (confidence of the model that this particular input example corresponds to each possible label. The largest value in the array correspond to the most likely class (prediction) of your model for the input. If you want to calculate top-5 accuracy, you check (for every input) if one of the 5 largest values in the array correspond to the correct label. If that's the case, you treat this example as correctly classified, then count the total number of correctly classified examples, divide by the total number of examples, and multiply by 100 to get your percentage.

Comment: yes but is there a way that I can round this off  at least the hundredths place.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What do you want to round and why?

Comment: I can't print out scientific notations as confidence values so is there a way a can convert those floats to percentage.

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate probabilities? Then you would need to use softmax function.